# submit button 'depressed' state on focus -- potential chrome bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome

What's with submit buttons in Chrome?

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Dummy Input'/>
<input type='submit'/>
```

The active 'depressed' state of the submit button will only occur if the button **does not** have focus. To reproduce, see [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BABE/2/). In fact, the text-field isn't really even necessary, only to allow <kbd>tab</kbd> focus into the submit button.

So go ahead, place cursor in text field, press <kbd>tab</kbd> and click submit while the button is focused (orange). The event fires, but the button does **not** depress.

Pressing <kbd>spacebar</kbd> when focused instead of click *will* depress the button. (thx @Ineentho) What gives?

**Note: I've [submitted this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240137) to the Chrome Issue Tracker**

Comment: Works for me... I don't see what your problem is. Which browser?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: just tried it in FF and works. Not working in Chrome 27.0.1453.73 (Ubuntu Linux)

Comment: yep trying with chrome and i have the problem too

Comment: interesting thing is that if you "click it" with space, it works. Looks like a chrome bug to me

Comment: @Ineentho good catch. yeah looks like chrome bug.

Comment: this does not work in IE10 either.

Comment: This is most definitely a bug, one I can't find in the [open issues list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/) yet, also reproducable in 27.0.1453.81 beta-m on Windows. You should submit it.

Comment: [Submitted](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240137)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Confirmed Chrome bug.

See submitted issue: [Chrome Issue 240137](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=240137) which was just merged into [Chrome Issue 238560](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238560).

*Giving bounty to [@SzőkePéter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104978/szoke-peter) for providing a temporary workaround.*

Comment: FYI: This appears fixed in Chrome 30, at least, and has been closed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some javascript/jquery to un-focus the textbox on hover so the :active properties would be applied when clicked.

```
$("input[type=submit]").hover(function(){
     $(this).blur();
});
```

Also, you could apply css to the :focus pseudoclass, so the outline would always be invisible.

```
input[type=submit]:focus {outline:none;}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qahcJ/1/

**UPDATE**

I think that you can't solve this without Javascript hack, so here is a much simpler way to do it. Just use this piece of code:

```
$("input[type=submit]").bind("mousedown",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gFMTt/

Comment: Thanks, but I'd still like focus (tab) to highlight the submit button. This shouldn't need any javascript hackery... I'm more interested in why CSS is acting like this.

Comment: There's still outline for some reason.

Comment: @JordanArseno even without any styling i realized it is doing the same thing. when on focus, you need to click twice to actually click the button

Comment: Interesting, @btevfik, thank you, I will update the JSFiddle + Question.

Comment: For the first time I thought that :focus may override :active but I couldn't find out if I am right.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9BABE/2/ ok the click is actually registered. but on focus, the color of the button does not change when you click. it stays grey. if not on focus, then it changes to blue. i am testing on mac, chrome. @JordanArseno

Comment: Very nice @btevfik -- so we see... the event seems to fire, but the style is all botched and the button won't inset. Updating question with your JSFiddle.

Comment: @SzőkePéter i think that is still not the expected behavior. if you try in firefox you will see what we expect. we expect that on focus, the button has some border indicating it is focused, and when you click on it, the border should dissapper and the the button color or style should change accordingly.

Comment: thx, @SzőkePéter for this. +1 It does indeed work, and I will be glad to accept it, provided that answers citing the spec, or, chrome bug tracker don't come in. Cheers!